# При уменьшении ширины экрана задний фон скатываться в левый край как исправить?

Tags: html, css

При уменьшении ширины экрана задний фон скатываться в левый край как исправить  ?

```html
<div  class="about_my_bg" id="about_us">
        <div class="about_my_container">
            <div class="about_my_wrapper">
                <div class="about_my_title">
                    <h1>About me</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="about_my_sub_title">
                    <p>Hi, I'm Denis – UX/UI designer from Minsk. <br> I'm interested in design and everything connected with it. <br><br><br> I'm studying at courses "Web and mobile design <br> interfaces" in IT-Academy. <br><br><br> Ready to implement excellent projects <br> with wonderful people.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.about_my_bg {
    background: #F6F6F6;
    width: 100%;
}
.about_my_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 943px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.about_my_wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 107px;
}
.about_my_title h1 {
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #070707;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.about_my_sub_title p {
    color: #070707;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

[image: ggg]

Знаю что вопрос наверное очень простой но все же буду рад если кто то укажет на мою ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно убрать ширину из `.about_my_container`. Вот, как по итогу должно выглядеть -

```
.about_my_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
     /*width: 943px;*/
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: В CSS `//` - так нельзя комментировать

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на ошибку. Исправил 
(Привык, что вы дарте //)

Comment: @Daniil елси вам все же нужен контейнер но чтоб он был резиновый, вместо width используйте max-width